# Nautilus to open in the foreground

Tags: terminal, nautilus

From the terminal I can open the file manager using `nautilus .`, but the window opens behind the current terminal window (on my Ubuntu 14.04).

Is there a way to call `nautilus` from the terminal and bring the window to the foreground?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. My window manager is compiz. Can you mention which window manager you're using? It might depend on the window manager.

Comment: @Celada compiz. Default Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same issue in Ubuntu 14.04. Please watch quick video which I made about this issue: https://youtu.be/2RFb_ed7230  compizconfig-settings-manager: 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20141104-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding comment here I checked [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428764/windows-that-pop-up-appear-behind-active-window) and found the answer there.

> You need to install `CompizConfig Settings Manager`. Then go to `General`
>   -> `General Options` -> `Focus & Raise Behaviour` and set `Focus Prevention Level` from `Low` to `Off`.

Comment: Just a clarification that the name of the package is actually the whole name: `CompizConfig Settings Manager` and that it can be installed via the `Ubuntu Software Center`